# How to get nodes in neo4j based on property value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created some nodes with a property called: color. I haven't assigned any values to this property.
Now I want to write a query to get all the nodes which have this property "NULL".

My query is this:

```
  MATCH (n:Image) WHERE n.color='' RETURN n
```

But this returns nothing. How can I get all the nodes which belong to the label:Image and have the property:Color empty?

I also tried this with no luck:

```
MATCH (n:Image) WHERE n.color IS NULL RETURN n
```

Thanks
D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Null isn't a valid property value- if values are not assigned, or explicitly assigned null, then the property doesn't exist on the node.

You can use either

```
MATCH (n:Image) where not(has(n.color)) return n
```

to check if the property exists on the node or simply

```
MATCH (n:Image) where n.color IS NULL
```

Based on comments below, an empty String is not the same as a missing property/null value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I might make a mistake here. When I created the nodes I did it like this: CREATE (n:Image {Color:' ', Path: 'pic.jpg'})  Now I understand that Color is not really empty in this case. Right? How can I create the node together with the Color property being empty?

Comment: This is different- the id property is stored on the node with an empty string value. In this case match (n:Image) where n.id='' return n will return these nodes. Empty string values are stored, missing/nulls are not

Comment: That actually worked! I keep forgetting the case sensitive thing of neo4j. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: In my experience if a property is unassigned then `node.property IS NULL` will garner a match.

Comment: You're right. The issue turned out to be empty strings. Editing my answer, thanks

Comment: I get the the function `has` does not exist is the syntax different today?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me: `WHERE not (toString(n.color) = '')`